# Xamarin Android Visual Studio let deploy override app

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I use visual studio 2015 with xamarin android for my project. I build and debug on a Samsung SM-G389F(Android 6.0 - API 23). Everytime I build my project and deploy it to my device it will not override the previously build app. I have to manually delete the existing app in order to see some changes.

Is there a way in visual studio to let the app be successfully deployed?
Is this a bug or are my settings wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might have Fast assembly deployment enabled and it's not working correctly. Here's what to do:

1. Go to project's properties and Android Options tab.
2. Turn off *Use Fast Deployment*
3. Uninstall the app completely from the device.
4. Rebuild the whole project (rebuild also does cleans the project)
5. Try to deploy again